# Unable to create typeguard in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a typeguard in TypeScript which identifies if the value passed is the subtype SubThing of the generic Thing.

Here's the code:

```
interface Thing<T extends number = number> {
  one: T;
  two: number;
}

type SubThing = Thing<1>;

const isSubThing = <TThing extends Thing>(thing: TThing): thing is SubThing =>
  thing.one === 1;
```

I get the error message:

"A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
Type 'SubThing' is not assignable to type 'TThing'.
'SubThing' is assignable to the constraint of type 'TThing', but 'TThing' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Thing'."

It seems to be complaining because Thing is less specific than SubThing, but my understanding was that that was the point of typeguards; that they allow you to inform TypeScript to narrow the type given the truth of the return value.

What am I missing here and what approach should I take to achieve what I'm after, i.e. a way to identify a narrower type based on the value of the `one` property on the `thing` object?

Comment: It's complaining because `TThing` might be narrower than `Thing` in way unrelated to `SubThing`; type predicates must be seen as a narrowing of the type.  You can fix it either by removing generics entirely (it should work just as well without generics) or by having the return type `thing is TThing & SubThing`.  As shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mqpPrN).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer or point to a suitable dupe target. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Ah of course, I totally don't need generics here anyway do I. And yes, the error is complaining about `TThing` not `Thing`.

I think is the answer yeah. Thanks a lot!

Yeah I will mark that as the answer if you write it up.